# Remove "Line 1" from checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a magento 2 shop.

In the checkout summary there is an annoying line which i cannot find to rename.

The street line it's label is

```
Street: Line 1
```

How can i remove the line 1.

I have tried:

```
1. en_EN.csv ...
2. modifying register.phtml
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They translation for the street field labels are the same.

The string to translate is `"%1: Line %2"`

You can remove the line part by doing something like `"%1: Line %2","%1"` in the theme translation file for you locale.

This will as mentioned affect all street lines not just street 1

Comment: Thank you so much.it works

Answer (score 1):

No the proper solution that works is but it is good . Try following way :-

```
[name*="shippingAddress.street.0"] .label {display: none;}
```

**`THANKS`**

Comment: Thank you. i only want to remove Line 1 from the street. Css is unfortunately not a solution here